# Error to deploy Rails on GAE

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, google-app-engine

I am getting this error when the deploy to GAE (RoR) is finished:

```
latest: digest: sha256:fae8a83d8a4503b9ca284ecfb70da5faf1b66b015804396c2282fae7fc5e4669 size: 75429
DONE
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Updating service [default]...failed.
ERROR: (gcloud.preview.app.deploy) Error Response: [13] The system encountered a fatal error
```

I have no idea what happens.

I checked the logs, and last register is about the docker build:

17:13:24.410
DONE
{
metadata:
{…}
textPayload:
"DONE"
insertId:
"271f3953-7ca6-4282-960a-fcb35a2261a2-316"
log:
"cloudbuild"
}

The application is running in development and production enviroment whitout errors.

- Rails : 4.2.6
- Ruby: 2.3.1
- GCloud SDK: 108.0.0

Someone knows how to fix it?

Very thanks!

Comment: I've just started experiencing the same problem. The timing of it makes me think maybe there is something wrong with AppEngine at the moment.

Comment: Deploy worked with `--docker-build=remote` option. Anyway I opened a ticket on google support.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Temporally solve:

Just add `--docker-build=remote` option to you `gcloud preview app deploy` command. (Remote builds are working normally)

To debug the command use `--verbosity debug` option.

EDIT:

Response from google support:

`Engineering is aware of an issue with the platform that would cause these errors. They are currently working on deploying a fix.`